# Android Crashlytics unset string

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

Crashlytics allows [strings to be sent with crash logs](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.2.4/com/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics.html#setString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but how can they be unset?

Let's say I working on a media player. Sometimes I want to send a non fatal log with a media id. Other times I want to send a log without a media id.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `null` as a value in the arguments

```
String key = "mediaId";
Crashlytics.setString(key, null);
```

There is check inside this method if value is `null` then it will set empty string:

```
public void setString(String key, String value) {
    // some code
    value = value == null ? "" : sanitizeAttribute(value);
    //some code
}
```

**EDIT**

The only way to this is reinitialize the crashlytics:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

Your kyes are stored inside `CrashlyticsCore`'s map 
`private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> attributes;` and there is no possibility to get those values and remove some of your keys except init it in the Builder class.

Comment: This does not unset the value, right? It just sets it to an empty string. I don't want to send the key at all.

Comment: @alexbirkett Yes you are right, I have added some changes to the answear

Comment: The SDK stores it in its cache which is another ConcurrentHashMap which lies in the CrashlyticsController class. This cache holds the userIdentifier and the userName. I couldn't find any method to clear it. The data once put in the core stays in the cache.