# Flutter Crashlytics Remove CustomKey

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics in my Flutter app through [`firebase_crashlytics`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) package.

I read that I can use custom key to send additional data with `setCustomKey` method. However, I couldn't find a way to remove it for the next error report.

Here is my `firebase_logger.dart`

```
class FirebaseLogger implements ILogger {
  FirebaseCrashlytics get _crashlytics => FirebaseCrashlytics.instance;

  @override
  Future<void> init() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> trackError(
    String name, {
    Map<String, String> properties,
    dynamic exception,
    StackTrace stackTrace,
  }) async {
    final String userId = getUserId();
    if (userId != null) _crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(userId);

    properties.forEach((key, value) {
      _crashlytics.setCustomKey(key, value);
    });
    _crashlytics.recordError(exception, stackTrace);

    // Clear the keys for the next log    
    properties.forEach((key, value) {
      _crashlytics.setCustomKey(key, '');
    });
    if (employeeId != null) _crashlytics.setUserIdentifier('');
    
  }
}
```

and here are my error methods:

```
  Future<void> testError1() async {
    try {
      throw Exception('error 1');
    } catch (e, s) {
      await _logger.trackError(
        'testError1',
        properties: {'name1': 'name 1', 'id1': 'id 1'},
        exception: e,
        stackTrace: s,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> testError2() async {
    try {
      throw Exception('error 2');
    } catch (e, s) {
      await _logger.trackError(
        'testError2',
        properties: {'name2': 'name 2', 'id2': 'id 2'},
        exception: e,
        stackTrace: s,
      );
    }
  }
```

I tried triggering `testError1` and then `testError2`.
I read [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092495/android-crashlytics-unset-string) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255778/crashlyticsandroid-clear-log-before-next-crash) (which may not valid anymore) that I had to set it null or empty in android SDK, but in flutter they checked it with assert not null. Giving them empty value gave the result of `testError2` empty `id1` and `name1` properties. Is there a way to reset the keys/properties?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem where unsetting custom key/value pairs after calling recordError clears those entries in the dashboard.